# 'uninitialized constant ActionPack' when starting rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, bundler, actionpack, startup-error

When starting my rails server I'm getting an 'uninitialized constant ActionPack' error.

[raw stack trace](http://pastie.org/987517.txt)

I'm using blunder with rails 2.3.8

running 'bundle list' shows:

```
  * actionmailer (2.3.8)
  * actionpack (2.3.8)
  * activerecord (2.3.8)
  * activeresource (2.3.8)
  * activesupport (2.3.8)
  * acts-as-taggable-on (2.0.6)
  * authlogic (2.1.5)
  * builder (2.1.2)
  * cucumber (0.7.3)
  * cucumber-rails (0.3.1)
  * database_cleaner (0.5.2)
  * diff-lcs (1.1.2)
  * faker (0.3.1)
  * gherkin (1.0.30)
  * haml (3.0.7)
  * hoe (2.6.0)
  * json_pure (1.4.3)
  * machinist (1.0.6)
  * nifty-generators (0.4.0)
  * nokogiri (1.4.2)
  * rack (1.1.0)
  * rack-test (0.5.4)
  * rails (2.3.8)
  * rake (0.8.7)
  * rr (0.10.11)
  * rspec (1.3.0)
  * rspec-rails (1.3.2)
  * rubyforge (2.0.4)
  * sqlite3-ruby (1.2.5)
  * term-ansicolor (1.0.5)
  * test-unit (1.2.3)
  * trollop (1.16.2)
  * webrat (0.7.1)
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's a bug in Haml 3.0.7. You can see it http://github.com/nex3/haml/issues#issue/186

So you can add in your bundler :

```
gem 'actionpack', :require => 'action_pack'
```

Or you can wait the next release of Haml.

Update: The next release is now out, it's the 3.0.8. It's fix this problem.

Comment: The bug is only in Haml 3.0.7; 3.0.8 fixes it.